# In Ruby, what are the use cases for adding methods to an instance's singleton class?

Tags: ruby, methods, singleton, instance, metaclass

Thanks to some other posts and reading, I understand singleton/meta classes. And I understand why we'd want to use them on a class. But I still don't understand why we'd want to use them on instance objects. And I've yet to see it in practice.

I'm referring to something like this:

```
class Vehicle
    def odometer_reading
        # some code
    end
end

my_car = Vehicle.new

def my_car.open_door
    # some code
end
```

At first thought, this seems like a bad idea as it would lead to difficulties in understanding the code and debugging.

Why would we want to do this?  What are some examples of when this is a good idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One example is using it for testing purposes: creating mock and double objects, stubbing methods. Debugging is somewhere nearby: re-defining the logging method for a specific object that you suspect is mis-behaving, so that the log info is printed directly to console (or more info is printed) during the debug session.

Another example is dealing with special cases - instead of inheritance you can do just that. Starting from a classical example if you use two types of `Employee`s, say, `Engineer`s and `SalesPerson`s, for which the rules of compensation calculation are different, you can put the common logic into the `Employee` class, then inherit the other two classes from it and implement their own `calculate_salary` methods there. Now, if there is an outlier - a star salesman that you have agreed to a different compensation scheme with, a CEO with a very special scheme, etc - instead of creating a whole sub-class for this special employee, you can just define this method for a specific object representing that employee.

The third example is dealing with an object lifecycle and performance considerations. Instead of having a long `case` of various states in some processing method. E.g. for a file-reading class that transparently caches the entire file in the background (I know a too-simplistic-for-real-life approach, but just as a model) all read requests while the file is not entirely read should check if the requested data is already in the cache or should be read from disk. Once the file is fully read they always go from the cache. Instead of having the `if` (`case` if there are more states) to deal with this you could simply re-define the `read` method at the object-level once the file is fully read to the cache. For this simple example it doesn't lead to any sizable performance benefit (if any benefit at all), but for more complex cases that may be worth it.

Comment: Thanks for the concrete examples. If we were to do this, is considered good practice by the programming community, let alone the Ruby community?  As you can tell, I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around the idea that this a good idea.

Comment: Yes, to me seems like a good practice - very Ruby-way-ish.
A couple of links after some (very quick) googling:
http://blog.flatironschool.com/post/67061115355/demystifying-singleton-classes-and-methods - they think it's good (& used under-the-hood for class methods anyways).
This post (http://bettong.net/2011/11/07/notes-on-eloquent-ruby-number-3/) refers to this approach suggested by the "Eloquent Ruby" book. Now, I don't have the book here at hand, but the book is almost classic (well, to me for sure), and the author says it's good and is an example of proper "Ruby way" then probably it is.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't add them using `def`, that's a rather rigid way of doing it, but instead by using something like `define_method` or `extend`.

Although this is not the sort of thing you'd do on a routine basis, it does mean you can do some rather unusual things. ActiveRecord in Rails produces results in the form of an Array with additional methods added on to perform other operations.

An Object-Relationship Mapper would be a case where you'd probably want to do this. Sometimes, depending on how you fetch a record, the methods available differ significantly. Being able to add those dynamically means each fetched object can be completely customized even if they have the same class and general-purpose methods.

Comment: I see. When you say "do some rather unusual things", that's where I'm coming from. Why do we want to do unusual things? I guess in very specific cases where it's relatively safe to do so, its fine.

Comment: Here's an example [in another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26266552/refactoring-ruby-scraping-code) using metaprogramming that responds to the structure of a document.

Answer (score 0):

Another example: You have an array of hashes and you want each hash to have a method-call getter and setter. Something like:

```
user = HashOnSteroids.new(name: 'John')
user[:name] # => 'John'
user[:name] = 'Joe'
user.name # => 'Joe'
user.name = 'John'
user.set(name: 'Jim', age: 5)
```

This means you cannot write standard method definitions in the class as each hash will have a different set of keys (method names). This means you have to resort to defining singleton methods so each object has its own set of methods (not a pack of shared methods).

**Warning:** Using singleton methods for this use case is highly inefficient. A sneaky `method_missing` is faster and uses way less memory as it doesn't have to allocate a billion of proc objects.

Comment: [OpenStruct](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html) does something similar to this.

Comment: OpenStruct looks a lot like Javascript.

Comment: I know but it eats around 5 times more memory (MRI) and doesn't seem to support bulk set. Rolling our own solution was actually easy and also fun.