# refactoring Ruby scraping code

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

Basically, I will have multiple `.main_entry` blocks on each page and I will need to pull a couple of pieces of data from each. How can this be properly refactored into methods?

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'


url = #url
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

doc.css(".main_entry").each do |item|
  artist = item.at_css(".list_artist").text
  title = item.at_css(".list_album").text
  puts "#{artist} - #{title}"
end
```

I have arrived at this mess below, which throws the `undefined local variable or method 'release'` error that seems to be related to methods being over-written. Could you explain to me what process the code below goes through, why it breaks down and what I should turn to for the fix? Should each `.main_entry` block be saved into some kind of a cache or an array first, before instantiating?

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

class Scraper
  def initialize(url)
    @url = url
  end

  def release
    @release ||= doc.css(".main_entry") || []
  end

  release.each do |item|
    define_method(:artist) do
      @artist ||= item.at_css(".list_artist").text
    end

    define_method(:title) do
      @title ||= item.at_css(".list_album").text
    end
  end

  private
  attr_reader :url

  def doc
    @doc ||= Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
  end
end

scraper = Scraper.new( #url

puts "#{scraper.artist} - #{scraper.title}"
```

Comment: `release.each` won't call the instance method `release`, but instead it'll go looking for `Scraper.release` which you haven't defined. You could always move that inside the `initialize` method.

Comment: @tadman how would this look exactly? `def initialize(url, release) ... @release = Scraper.release` and then a separate `def release ... @release = ...`?

Comment: You need to supply sample HTML demonstrating what you want to do. Don't make us invent it please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my suggestion:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

class ScrapedRelease
  attr_reader :item

  def initialize(item)
    @item = item
  end

  def artist
    @artist ||= item.at_css(".list_artist").text
  end

  def title
    @title ||= item.at_css(".list_album").text
  end
end

class Scraper
  def initialize(url)
    @url = url
  end

  def releases
    @releases ||= (doc.css(".main_entry") || []).map { |item| ScrapedRelease.new(item) }
  end

  private
  attr_reader :url

  def doc
    @doc ||= Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
  end
end
```

Then you can do:

```
Scraper.new(url).releases.each do |release|
  puts "#{release.artist} - #{release.title}"
end
```

Comment: Whoa, that is amazing! Need to dedicate a lot more time to studying examples like this.

Comment: Btw, if you are on Ruby 2.x then instead of `(doc.css(".main_entry") || [])` you can do `Array(doc.css(".main_entry"))`, which is much more elegant to me. That's because `Array(nil)` is `[]`.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed the `|| []` part and only checked `nil || []` in the console, assuming `Array(nil)` is `nil`. So it's really good that you clarified this! And yes, I'm using 2.x